# Django : Cant include static files in webpage

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-staticfiles, django-1.9

I know there are a few questions like this, but none of them have worked for me. I have django version 1.9.2. The documentation was not of much help wither as i found it quite confusing. Here is my set up

```
myApp-

      static-
              myApp-
                    scripts-
                            scripts.js
                    images-
                            xyz.png
      templates-
              myApp-

                    index.html
```

in my `settings.py` i have

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'campaign.apps.CampaignConfig'
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and my webpage has

```
<script language="javascript">var STATIC_URL = '/static/';</script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}myApp/scripts/scripts.js"></script>
```

and this does not get recognized. neither does this

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}myApp/images/xyz.png">
```

what other changes do i need to make? Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Why would you think that setting a JS variable would help?

Comment: i got it from one of the solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the `static` template tag

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'myApp/images/xyz.png' %}">
```

Comment: Also, make sure you have ran `collectstatic`.

Comment: i get  You're using the staticfiles app without having
 set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.

Comment: if i do,  STATIC_ROOT = '/static/' i get You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    C:\static

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: i tried to set the static root to the absolute path of my static folder. then i rant the collectstatic and got WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: